# Add map to list if no map with such key in list ELSE increment value in map

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am looking for a way to insert a new map in a list **if** no map with such `key` in this list already exists, **if** exists -> increment `valueNum`.

```
mylist [
  mymap1: {
    key1: valueNum,
    key2: otherValue
  }
]
```

Is it possible in one query, with returning of item?

Comment: Do you have any other attribute in mymap1 other than key attribute?

Comment: Yes, updated example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified my schema to few additional tables without such deep structures.